# Redirecting desktop traffic from Google & ampproject.org Cached URLs to Non-Amp URLs

Tags: amp-html

Our our site redirects mobile traffic to URLs ending with /amp/ where the AMP pages are located.

We want desktop users to be strictly unable to reach our AMP URLs.

We are able to divert destop users from:
http://www.example.com/amp/
to
http://www.example.com
easily.

But we are not able redirect desktop visitors to non-AMP urls when they reach us from google or ampproject.org cache addresses located at:
https://www-example-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/www.example.com/amp/
or
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.example.com/amp/
(
they do reach from both for some reasons)

Our aim is to let mobile users reach AMP version of URLs (directly or via google cache,) but we want desktop users to be strictly directed to the non-amp version of the corresponding URL even if they reach Google or Ampproject cached AMP URLs.

Any ideas on how we can do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have set your "canonical" and "amphtml" links properly in your AMP page and your non AMP page respectively, than this will be handled automatically by Google.
If some one Google your website from desktop than he/she want be able to see AMP version. he/she will be redirect to non AMP version only. And suppose someone tries to open your AMP cache URL directly in desktop than that also will redirect to your canonical page only.Try to open this page in your desktop : https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.ndtv.com/india-news/isros-baahubali-gslv-mk-iii-d2-indias-heaviest-rocket-lifts-off-successfully-from-sriharikota-1947348%3famp=1&akamai-rum=off

This is an AMP cache URL it will redirect to your canonical one when your open it in a desktop. While if you Google "India news" this page will open from Google AMP cache.
If someone hits AMP URL in desktop than only he/she can see that AMP page in desktop. Other wise from Google search list he/she will be redirected to canonical version only.